# MapThread with incompatible length (How to Map twice in the same line)

Tags: list-manipulation, map

`l` and `b` are two lists of vectors with different length. I need the list of vectors that is constructed by adding each member of `b` to each member of `l` (resulting in a list with length $|l|\times |b|$). This can be done by

```
t = Join@Flatten[Table[Map[# + b[[i]] &, l], {i, Length[b]}], 1]
```

Can this be done by mapping something like `#1+#2&` to the lists? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Outer` and `Tuples` may be helpful, e.g.

```
l1 = {1, 2, 3}
l2 = {4, 5, 6, 7}
Total /@ Tuples[{l1, l2}]
Join @@ Outer[Plus, l1, l2]
```

yields:{5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 10}

or symbolically,

```
Join @@ Outer[Plus, {a, b, c}, {d, e, f, g, h}]
```

gives: {a + d, a + e, a + f, a + g, a + h, b + d, b + e, b + f, b + g, b + h,
  c + d, c + e, c + f, c + g, c + h}